# How can I compare Javascript dates to filter objects in an array?

Tags: javascript, json

I've been stuck on this for days and dates in JavaScript are quite confusing.
I need to iterate some JSON and filter objects that are less than 2h ahead and more than 2 months ahead.

here is an example of the JSON:

```
[
   {
      "Email":"example@email.com",
      "TimeSlotsDate":"2017-01-28",
      "TimeSlotsAvailable":[
         {
            "start":"11:00",
            "end":"12:00"
         },
         {
            "start":"12:00",
            "end":"13:00"
         },
         {
            "start":"13:00",
            "end":"14:00"
         },
         {
            "start":"15:00",
            "end":"16:00"
         },
         {
            "start":"16:00",
            "end":"17:00"
         },
         {
            "start":"17:00",
            "end":"18:00"
         }
      ],
   },
   {
      "Email":"example@email.com",
      "TimeSlotsDate":"2017-02-01",
      "TimeSlotsAvailable":[
         {
            "start":"12:00",
            "end":"13:00"
         },
         {
            "start":"13:00",
            "end":"14:00"
         },
         {
            "start":"14:00",
            "end":"15:00"
         },
         {
            "start":"15:00",
            "end":"16:00"
         },
         {
            "start":"16:00",
            "end":"17:00"
         },
         {
            "start":"17:00",
            "end":"18:00"
         }
      ],
   }]
```

I have written a function that creates usable dates from the JSON but I am stuck at the part where I remove the objects from the `TimeSlotsAvailable` array that are less than 2h ahead and more than 2 months ahead as mentioned.

Here is the function:

```
var filterTimeslots = function (_timeSlots) {

    var result = [];
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var timeZoneOffset = currentDate.getTimezoneOffset() / 60;  

    for (var i in _timeSlots) {
        var day = _timeSlots[i].TimeSlotsDate.substring(8, 10);
        var month = _timeSlots[i].TimeSlotsDate.substring(5, 7);
        var year = _timeSlots[i].TimeSlotsDate.substring(0, 4);

        for (var x in _timeSlots[i].TimeSlotsAvailable) {
            var timeSlotStrt = _timeSlots[i].TimeSlotsAvailable[x].start.substring(0, 2);
            var timeZoneTime = parseInt(timeSlotStrt) - timeZoneOffset;

            var timeSlotDate = new Date(year, month, day, timeZoneTime);

            if (timeSlotDate < currentDate) {
                //the timeslot is less than 2 hours away
            }

            if (timeSlotDate > currentDate) {
                //the timeslot is more than 2 months ahead
            }   

            return result;
        }
    }
};
```

The function should return a filtered array that excludes the invalid time slots.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I suggest using library like http://momentjs.com/

Answer (score 0):

using moment should be easy

```js
var arr = [{
  "Email": "example@email.com",
  "TimeSlotsDate": "2016-08-16",
  "TimeSlotsAvailable": [{
    "start": "17:00",
    "end": "18:00"
  }],
}, {
  "Email": "example@email.com",
  "TimeSlotsDate": "2017-02-08",
  "TimeSlotsAvailable": [{
    "start": "11:00",
    "end": "12:00"
  }, {
    "start": "12:00",
    "end": "13:00"
  }, {
    "start": "13:00",
    "end": "14:00"
  }, {
    "start": "15:00",
    "end": "16:00"
  }, {
    "start": "16:00",
    "end": "17:00"
  }, {
    "start": "17:00",
    "end": "18:00"
  }],
}, {
  "Email": "example@email.com",
  "TimeSlotsDate": "2017-02-01",
  "TimeSlotsAvailable": [{
    "start": "12:00",
    "end": "13:00"
  }, {
    "start": "13:00",
    "end": "14:00"
  }, {
    "start": "14:00",
    "end": "15:00"
  }, {
    "start": "15:00",
    "end": "16:00"
  }, {
    "start": "16:00",
    "end": "17:00"
  }, {
    "start": "17:00",
    "end": "18:00"
  }],
}];
var now = moment();
var start = now.clone().add(2, 'hours');
var end = now.clone().add(2, "months");
console.log("NOW: ",now);
console.log("START: ",start);
console.log("END: ",end);
var res = arr.filter(function(el) {
  return el.TimeSlotsAvailable.filter(function(subEl) {
    var c = moment(el.TimeSlotsDate + " " + subEl.start);
    return c >= start && c <= end;
  }).length == el.TimeSlotsAvailable.length;
});
console.log(res.length, res);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/moment.js/2.14.1/moment.min.js"></script>
```